# 1995 600r ninja boggs out during 4th -5th gear WOT between 8-10,000rpm

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, ninja

in 4th and 5th gear Wide Open Throttle the bike bogs out between 8-10 thousand rpm. I roll off the throttle...then slowly roll it back on to get through the flat spot. If i ring the gears out WOT it works fine it only happens during 4th and 5th gear WOT. It feels like its starves for fuel for a short period of time so i let off and re apply throttle and it works through it.Carbs were cleaned 2 weeks ago due to bogging out when accelerating all the time. One of the float bowls had a milky substance in bottom ,main jet was also clogged. I cleaned them,added new air -gas filters.

Comment: So, what is your question? Also i fail to see how 10,000rpm is considered mid-range...

Comment: It is fairly mid range, considering red line is at 14000rpm, and you'll be at 7000rpm and over most of the time.

Answer (score -1):

Have another look at those float bowls.  An engine uses roughly twice as much fuel at WOT compared to cruising speeds, so it very well indeed may be starved for fuel.  Another consideration may be air leaks somewhere in the manifold, vac. lines, carb gaskets, which will cause a lean condition that is most pronounced at WOT (and can lead to rapid overheating of the cylinder head and seizure of the engine).

You could try using Marvel Mystery Oil in the gas tank at a treat rate of 2 oz. per gallon to clear any minor clogs in the fuel system.

Comment: thank you @Carguy. When the rain stops i will look into it and get back to you.